# How To Insert Raw Javascript Into Omega Template For Custom Content Type

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and the Omega Base theme with my subtheme created off of that. I created a custom content type that has fields mapped to use the "Feeds" module to import nodes with images. That is all working.

What I need to do is apply a javascript slideshow to the images that are in each node so they rotate (some nodes have more than one image).

Can anyone tell me how to add javascript to the Omega template file so that it applies the javascript to ALL of the nodes created when I import the data from the "Feeds" module?

I can't even get a preview to work using firebug. Stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to copy "html.tpl.php" from omega/templates/ to YourTheme/templates/ folder.  Then, add the Javascript just above the < /body> tag at the bottom of the page.  This will make the Javascript applied throughout the website.

If you need to apply only to a particular content type you create, copy "node.tpl.php" from omega/templates/ to YourTheme/templates/ folder and rename it to "node--Your_Content_Type_Name.tpl.php".  (Note the double-dashes and underscores!).  Then add the Javascript to this file.

Comment: Will javascript allow me to create a rotating slideshow using div classes rather then actual image files? The image file names will be different on each node, but the div class that houses those images will be the same for the entire site. I can't seem to find out how to build the slideshow using divs over actual images.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but have you looked at Flexslider module (https://drupal.org/project/flexslider)?  It can combine multiple nodes and display them in a single slideshow.  It's also responsive and goes well with Omega theme.  There are even video tutorials.

Comment: Thanks. Here's my goal. I am importing a database (as nodes of custom content type). Each node has image fields that I added to import images into each node. There are multiple image fields per node. I need to create a slide show that will rotate (fade) between the images that were imported into each node. I need it to do that for each imported. I will have thousands of nodes imported, so I need it applied to every node that I import. I thought I might be able to insert javascript into the tmpl file, but as my javascript skills are novice, I can't seem to get it to work. Any help?